# PySpark Environment Setup for Pandas UDF

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dataframe, pyspark, bigdata

-EDIT-

This simple example just shows 3 records but I need to do this for billions of records so I need to use a Pandas UDF rather than just converting the Spark DF to a Pandas DF and using a simple apply.

Input Data

[image]

Desired Output

[image]

-END EDIT-

I've been banging my head against a wall trying to solve this and I'm hoping someone can help me with this.  I'm trying to convert latitude / longitude values in a PySpark dataframe to a Uber's H3 hex system.  This is a pretty straightforward use of the function `h3.geo_to_h3(lat=lat, lng=lon, resolution=7)`.  However I keep having issues with my PySpark Cluster.

I'm setting up my PySpark cluster as described in the databricks article [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/12/22/how-to-manage-python-dependencies-in-pyspark.html), using the following commands:

1. `conda create -y -n pyspark_conda_env -c conda-forge pyarrow pandas h3 numpy python=3.7 conda-pack`
2. `conda init --all` then closing and reopening the terminal window
3. `conda activate pyspark_conda_env`
4. `conda pack -f -o pyspark_conda_env.tar.gz`

I include the tar.gz file I created when creating my spark cluster in my jupyter notebook like so `spark = SparkSession.builder.master("yarn").appName("test").config("spark.yarn.dist.archives","<path>/pyspark_conda_env.tar.gz#environment").getOrCreate()`

I have my pandas udf set up like this which I was able to get working on a single node spark cluster but am now having trouble on a cluster with multiple worker nodes:

```
#create udf to convert lat lon to h3 hex
def convert_to_h3(lat : pd.Series, lon : pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    import h3 as h3
    import numpy as np
    if ((None in [lat, lon]) | (np.isnan(lat))):
        return None
    else:
        return (h3.geo_to_h3(lat=lat, lng=lon, resolution=7))

@f.pandas_udf('string', f.PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def udf_convert_to_h3(lat : pd.Series, lon : pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    df = pd.DataFrame({'lat' : lat, 'lon' : lon})
    df['h3_res7'] = df.apply(lambda x : convert_to_h3(x['lat'], x['lon']), axis = 1)
    return df['h3_res7']
```

After creating the new column with the pandas udf and trying to view it:

```
trip_starts = trip_starts.withColumn('h3_res7', udf_convert_to_h3(f.col('latitude'), f.col('longitude')))
```

I get the following error:

```
21/07/15 20:05:22 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Requesting driver to remove executor 139 for reason Container marked as failed: container_1626376534301_0015_01_000158 on host: ip-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.aws.com. Exit status: -100. Diagnostics: Container released on a *lost* node.
```

I'm not sure what to do here as I've tried scaling down the number of records to a more manageable number and am still running into this issue.  Ideally I would like to figure out how to use the PySpark environments as described in the databricks blog post I linked rather than running a bootstrap script when spinning up the cluster due to company policies making bootstrap scripts more difficult to run.

Comment: Make it simple, give the sample data and expected output

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will edit the original post shortly!

Comment: Per your request @wwnde, I've added a simple example here.  Thank you!

Comment: @wwnde, any thoughts on this?

Comment: please see this answer maybe this is helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67869938/using-h3-library-with-pyspark-dataframe

Comment: @MuhammadUmarAmanat, thank you for the response.  I believe my example above already does what that solution you linked to is doing.  The issue I'm running into is creating the environment with packages installed which is described in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68457055/pyspark-load-packages-for-pandas-udfs?noredirect=1#comment120998598_68457055.

Comment: @zorrrba Referred answer is a pythonic way of creating pandas_udf for pyspark. Rest it does the same as described above, and one other thing is that applyInPanas is the easy way to do the same. See this link for more info https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by repartitioning my data into smaller partitions with fewer records in each partition.  This solved the problem for me.