# PySpark Load Packages for Pandas UDF's

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have tried following the Databricks blog post [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/12/22/how-to-manage-python-dependencies-in-pyspark.html) but unfortunately keep getting errors.  I'm trying to install pandas, pyarrow, numpy, and the h3 library and then be able to access those libraries on my PySpark cluster but following these instructions isn't working.

1. conda init --all (then close and reopen terminal)
2. conda create -y -n pyspark_conda_env -c conda-forge pyarrow pandas h3 numpy python=3.7.10 conda-pack
3. conda activate pyspark_conda_env
4. conda pack -f -o pyspark_conda_env.tar.gz

```
import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = "./environment/bin/python"
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(
    "spark.yarn.archive",  # 'spark.yarn.dist.archives' in YARN.
    "~/gzk/pyspark_conda_env.tar.gz#environment").getOrCreate()
```

I'm able to get this far but when I actually try to run a pandas udf I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`

How can I solve this problem and use pandas udf's?

Comment: are you using databricks? if yes, what databricks runtime is used?

Comment: @AlexOtt, I don't believe I'm using databricks. I'm launching an AWS EMR running EMR 6.2.0 and trying to run this from a jupyter notebook.  Would that cause a problem that I'm not using a databricks notebook?

For reference, this is able to run from Spark Submit but not from a jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue by writing a bootstrap script for my AWS EMR cluster that would install all the packages I needed on all the nodes.  I was never able to get the directions above to work properly.

Documentation on bootstrap scripts can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).